# Clone harddrives in raid5 configuration to larger hadrdrives

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, nas, clone, raid-5

If i sector clone 3 disks (2 x 3tb and 1 x 4tb) that have a raid 5 configuration to 3 new disks (3 x 4tb), will the raid 5 configuration work on the new disks right away, and put empty space at end of 2 4tb disks , or will this confuse the raid array and do i need to do manual order or editing to it?

Comment: The safe way would be to use the redundancy of your RAID and replace the drives one-by-one and for each drive use the RAID initialization and rebuild process (and wait for it to finishe before replacing the next drive).

Comment: To piggy-back on @Robert's comment, if you're using ZFS, you'll likely want to create a new pool with the new drives, then copy the data over from the old pool due to going from a pool with unequal disk sizes to disks all of the same size _(this may not apply to a hardware RAID config, but matters for software-based ZFS)_